# How to connect Spring MVC to a remote MongoDB, to use the MongoOperations interface?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, remote-server

I have setup MongoDB on a local and a remote server, IP: 10.11.12.13.
Connecting using the command-line works when I do the following:

```
mongo 10.11.12.13:27017 -u "root" -p "123456" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

Furthermore, connecting to localhost using the Spring MVC, works too, and below is my configuration XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <!-- For the autowired Classes -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example">
        <!-- Exclude the Web controllers from the Spring root configuration file -->
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex"
            expression="com.example.controller" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Enable @Aspect, @Before, @After -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

    <mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="localhost" port="27017" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="MockDB" mongo-ref="mongo" />


    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This is the pom.xml

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <org.springframework-version>3.2.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.springsecurity-version>3.2.0.RELEASE</org.springsecurity-version>
        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.1.8.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.27</mysql.version>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <apache-dbcp.version>1.4</apache-dbcp.version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <mockito-version>1.10.19</mockito-version>
        <assertj-version>1.5.0</assertj-version>
        <!-- MongoDB -->
        <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>
        <mongo.version>1.3.3.RELEASE</mongo.version>
    </properties>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Aspect Oriented support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-dbcp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${mongo.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

As mentioned, I am using MongoOperations Java interface to manage MongoDB.

I would like to be able to connect to a remote MongoDB just the way I am connecting using a command-line, so I can manage it with MongoOperations.
However, whatever I tried did not work, and I am stuck.  What am I supposed to do/change/add so I can connect to a remote MongoDB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you are using MongoDB 3.x. The connection options for Mongo in Spring are

```
<mongo:mongo-client id="mongoClient" host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}" credentials="user:password@database">
  <mongo:client-options ... />
</mongo:mongo-client>

<mongo:db-factory dbname="database" mongo-ref="mongoClient"/>
```

More here: [Spring Data MongoDB - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/)

The section related to authentication is: [17.1.3. Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-3.authentication)

In your particular case (using options from your example) it should be the following

```
<mongo:mongo-client id="mongoClient" host="10.11.12.13" port="27017" credentials="root:123456@admin">

<mongo:db-factory dbname="MockDB" mongo-ref="mongoClient"/>
```

P.S. It is generally recommended to use `<mongo:mongo-client>` instead `<mongo:mongo>` for 3.x version.

Comment: Thank you, I will test/accept it after the weekend, and let you know.

Comment: I am constantly getting an error, and don't know what to import in the <beans xlms...  "The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:mongo-client'."

Comment: What version of spring-data-mongodb are you using. The `mongo-client` is avaliable since v1.7. At the same time `mongo` was depricated.

Comment: If you have later version use the link to the latest XSD `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd` (without version specified). Right now you are referencing XSD of v1.3. If you are usign library of version prior 1.7 you have to update.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. A new error is: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [mongo-client]
 - Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [mongo-client] Offending resource: file [.../springmvc-mongodb-example-
  master/src/main/resources/spring/spring-config.xml]

Comment: Can you post your Spring dependency list with versions? I'm not sure right now whether this is a dependency version issue or something else.

Comment: please see the edit, pom.xml with dependencies/versions has been inputted, please let me know if you need anything else ? Thank you!

Comment: You have spring-data-mongo of version 1.3.3.RELEASE. The solution I'm suggesting requires at least 1.7.0.

Comment: Just verified that spring-data-mongo 1.7.0.RELEASE has Spring 4.0.9 as dependency. There is no guarantee that it will correctly work with your 3.2.6 version. You may try to (i) update spring to v4, (ii) ignore 4.0.9 dependencies of spring-data-mongo, (iii) go programmatic way, (iv) create own mongo client bean and configure it with xml.

Comment: thank you for your help, I will award you with +50, may it serve you well.

Answer (score 2):

If you want you can use a java class to configure mongoDB rather than an XML file.

The code below uses spring-boot and spring-data-mongo in order to access a remote MongoDB > 3.X instance.

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories()
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
    private Integer port;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
    private String ip;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String database;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.authenticationDatabase}")
    private String authDb;

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return database;
    }

    @Bean(name = "mongoClient")
    public MongoClient mongo() throws UnknownHostException {
        String connection = String.format("mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s", username, password, ip, authDb);
        return new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(connection));
    }
}
```

Then inside your view or service you can simply inject the bean *mongoClient*

Comment: Given the business logic, I must use the XML. How would it translate to XML ?  Edit: forgot to say, thank you.

Comment: You should use Java Config rather than XML https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950289/why-java-config-is-favorable-in-spring-boot-when-compared-to-xml-config . However If you need an XML file  @AlehMaksimovich answer seems correct. Here http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial you can read more about spring-data, mongo and config.

Comment: It is correct but for unknown reason, I am getting the error as explained in the comments. Would you happen to know how to avoid that error ?

Comment: why are you not using port in connection ?

Answer (score 0):

**lets Try this** may be it will resolve your problem

```
 <mongo:mongo host="${mongoDBHost}" port="${mongoDBPort}" id="mongo" />

    <bean id="mongoCredientials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
        <constructor-arg name="username" value="${mongoDBUserName}"/>
        <constructor-arg name="password" value="${mongoDBPassword}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoDbFactory" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo"/>
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${mongoDBName}"/>
        <constructor-arg name="credentials" ref="mongoCredientials"/>
    </bean>

    <mongo:mapping-converter id="mappingConverter" db-factory-ref="mongoDbFactory" />

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
        <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingConverter"/>
    </bean>
```

reference links:
[1](https://www.journaldev.com/4144/spring-data-mongodb-example)  [2](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-hello-world-example/) [3](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial)